# How to reboot/shutdown Windows 8 without the mouse?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8, shutdown

Nowadays on Windows 7, if I have no mouse on my computer I just press <kbd>Win Button</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:
[image]

This makes my computer  shutdown without needing to use a mouse. However, on Windows 8, I need the mouse to open that charms menu on the right side of the screen, open the "Settings" tab -> "Power" -> Then choose for "Shut down", "Sleep" or "Restart":

[image]

There is some keyboard shortcut to open these shutdown options on Windows 8 or another other way to do this without a mouse?

Comment: perhaps set your power settings to have the power button on your machine shutdown the computer when pressed? just a thought.

Comment: Not enough reputation to answer, but here it is. Shutdown: Win+X, U, U. Restart: Win+X, U, R. Modify the last letter, based on the displayed submenu, for other functions such as sleep. Simple.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to show the Desktop, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to show the shutdown dialog, and finally, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to shut down.

Comment: You can create a shortcut "C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /s /t 0"

Comment: Unreliable. If you have desktop applications open, you will end up closing them instead. Shutdown: Win+X, U, U. Restart: Win+X, U, R. Modify the last letter, based on the displayed submenu, for other functions such as sleep.

Comment: @Saber: This is to shut down from the desktop, not Modern UI. If you’re in a M. UI window, press Win+D twice. Apart from that, please go ahead and post that as your own answer. =)

Answer (score 59):

The easy, Win8-only way: Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, use the arrow keys to pick `Power` then enter.

The way that works even on NT 4: You can use the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to open the "Run" dialogue. Windows has a builtin program, `shutdown.exe`, which can be used to shutdown (duh), logoff or reboot the computer. `shutdown -r -t 0` will immediately start a reboot; `shutdown -s -t 0` will immediately start a shutdown. See the output of `shutdown /?` to know the rest of the options.

Comment: I wonder if press `Win` key then type the `shutdown` command directly  still works? In Windows 7 it works.

Comment: No need to use Win key, just start typing when in the metro Start interface, once you load the desktop all the Win key does is toggle between Desktop and Metro.

Comment: The metro interface however can't locate `shutdown` when you type it there (0 results for Apps, 2 for Settings (just normal `powercfg.cpl` things), 5 results for files (which is in source code I have locally)). You can, however, input `shutdown -r -t 0` in there and it'll work (tested with `shutdown -r -t 60` and `shutdown -a`).

Comment: `Win` + `I` brings you directly to the settings bar.

Comment: I use the `shutdown -s -f -t 0` technique everyday. Without it, every single XP instance I've owned would refuse to die.

Comment: @Moab Besides, the suggestion to press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type shutdown doesn't work because of the change in search behavior. Not because they removed the start menu, which if they really did, it would fail at the very first step. Pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd> button would do something else completely than launch the start menu/screen.

Comment: A quicker way is => windows key + D => alt F4 =>enter

Comment: This answer requires 14 keystrokes just to shut the computer down (11 if you use Win+I). In XP it was 3 keystrokes, in Win7 it was 3 or 4. Win+D, Alt+F4 is too awkward. Is there no easy way to shut down anymore?

Comment: @Luke: The best answer by far here is to remap the computer’s power button. :)

Answer (score 18):

Not exactly a shortcut, but a pretty fast way of doing this with only the keyboard would be to use `Win+R`, then either `shutdown /s /t 0` to shutdown or `shutdown /r /t 0` to reboot.

Comment: It would, but omitting the time flag makes the delay default to 30 seconds.

Answer (score 18):

Set your power settings to have the power button of your computer shut down your PC when pressed.

Answer (score 12):

My variation is to create a Metro tile which shuts down the machine, the benefit is you can tab to your tile, then press enter.

Start on the Windows 8 desktop, or in a new folder - anywhere except in the Start Menu folder!

Right-click, New, Shortcut.  Paste the instruction:

```
C:\windows\system32\shutdown /s /t 20 (remember the space between t and 20)
```

Name the shortcut after yourself, e.g. Guy's Shutdown, that way you will recognise it easily!

Use Windows Explorer to navigate to the crucial folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Paste your shortcut.  (In passing you can see it's not possible to create a new shortcut here)

It's reassuring to see your shortcut amongst the other Apps.

Return to the Metro UI start screen - Windows Key is the quickest way.

Tab, or use the arrow keys, to move to your shutdown tile, press enter.

Answer (score 7):

**Shutdown**: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>.

**Restart**: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>.

Credit: User [saber](https://superuser.com/users/164123/saber), from his/her comment on the original question above.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
Or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then use the arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to choose Shutdown.

Comment: @Sensi, Wow, how did you know the `Alt` `S` shortcut?

Answer (score 5):

## Options by default

#### Using the Windows 8 settings bar

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, use the arrow keys to pick `Power` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Choose `Shutdown` or `Restart` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(8 steps: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

#### Using the shutdown dialog, and hiding all programs

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> closes most Windows programs. If you hide all programs first with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and activate the Desktop, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> brings up the close Windows dialog.
If you are in the Metro interface part of Windows 8, you must press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> one more time.

(3 or 4 steps: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>[, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>], <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

#### Using the Run dialog

Since Windows XP you can use the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to open the "Run" dialogue. Windows has a builtin program, `shutdown.exe`, which can be used to shutdown, logoff or reboot the computer. `shutdown -r -t 0` will immediately start a reboot; `shutdown -s -t 0` will immediately start a shutdown. See the output of `shutdown /?` to know the rest of the options. Commands like `shutdown.exe -s -t 0` can also be typed or pasted and then executed in the Start screen.

(2 steps if previously and last used command: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

#### Using the Lock screen

You can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to access the Lock screen. There you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight the power button, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you can select `shutdown` or `reboot` with the arrow buttons and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You must wait a little before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

(6 steps: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps in one of my articles to create your own tile in Windows 8.

1. Go to `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
2. Right click > New > Shortcut
3. Enter `%windir%\system32\Shutdown.exe -s -t 0` as the location
   [image: New Shortcut]
4. Give it a name and click **Finish**
   [image: Finish]
5. Position the icon where you want it:
   [image: Shutdown Metro]

Optional:

1. Right click on the shortcut and select Properties
2. Click the **Change Icon...** button. (There is a power button icon in `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`
   [image: Shutdown icon]

To add the shortcut to the **All Apps** group:

1. In the shortcut properties, go to the **Security** tab
2. Add `All Application Packages` and make sure the **Read** and **Read & execute** permissions are enabled

For more information, see http://www.oostdam.info/index.php/sectie-blog/54-windows8/343-windows-8-create-a-shutdown-button

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

This is the source code:

```c#
namespace power
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to shutdown your computer now?", "Shutdown", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/s /t 0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a small program in C# that displays a dialog to confirm if you want to shutdown your PC. Simply pin it to Start!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could do this really easily with VBScript: https://gist.github.com/3980564 And it'll still let you set a custom icon.

Answer (score 3):

Removed my consumer preview already so I can't check this.

On all other versions of Windows I just repeatedly press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> until all windows are closed and the shutdown menu shows. Then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>