# What are some quick(er) ways to shut down Windows 8?

Tags: shutdown, windows-8

For shutting down Windows 8 I have to move them mouse to the right corner -> charms menu -> settings -> power -> shut down.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Most computers have a power button, and Windows 8 can be assigned a rule for what happens when you press the button. So I'd suggest setting the rule to shut down (instead of sleep, for example), and use the power button.

Comment: Pull the power cord, oh you meant properly shut down....

Comment: linked: http://superuser.com/q/408015/79358

Comment: Don't understand why I got two down votes. Is the question that bad? Isn't that a legitimate question, because it's quiet annoying to do all those steps.

Comment: I think this is an excellent question. I am really irritated by how they have hidden the shutdown command.

Comment: This question is awesome... I came to ask the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Found this WindowsTip. Awesome.

Answer (score 8):

Keep tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (Quit Program).

For more windows shortcuts see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449

The KB doesn't cover Windows 8 (yet), but it's a classic Windows hot-key (since at least Windows 95).

Also see: [How to reboot/shutdown Windows 8 without the mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/408015/how-to-reboot-shutdown-windows-8-without-the-mouse)

Another possible option: create a batch file or a shortcut that contains `shutdown -f -s -t 00` and put it on your desktop.

As Randolf West suggested: The power button on and ACPI enabled PC (generally all modern PCs) works well when configured to shutdown (instead of entering a sleep mode).

Another option: A power bar with a switch shuts off PCs **FAST**, but it's not a good idea. :)

Comment: For my Windows 8 PC, I did the `shutdown` trick, but just made a shortcut instead of an entire batch file. I have Graceful Shutdown, without the -f, and a Fast No-BS Shutdown with the -f

Comment: @Luke Nice tweak, added it in. :)

Comment: The other cool thing? When I create a shortcut on the desktop, it added it to Metro for me once I used it once

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl+Alt+Del and then select shutdown. Alt+F4 from desktop does the trick as well. Configuring power button is the best way though.

Comment: Shutdown isn't an option for me when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del.  Perhaps because I have multiple local accounts?  I see only `Lock`, `Switch user`, `Sign out`, `Change a password`, and `Task Manager`.

Comment: @Langdon it's the icon in the bottom right, that you have to click afterwards (shift + tab brings you there too).

Comment: offtopic: Hanselmann blogged about win 8 and some handy shortcuts. It's nice post. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows8ProductivityWhoMovedMyCheeseOhThereItIs.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to add a Shutdown button to your start screen. I found this information on [this site](http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-shutdown-windows-8-in-just-one-click). I am reposting it here for posterity sake and others who have this question. Note: This method does not Shutdown the computer using the Hybrid Boot Option in Windows 8.

**Instructions:**

1. Navigate to the desktop.
2. Right click on the desktop and select New -> Shortcut. A shortcut menu appears
3. Enter `shutdown /s /t 0` (that’s a zero) in the location box and hit Next.
4. Enter a name for the shortcut and click Finish. A new shortcut will appear on your desktop.
5. Right click on the shortcut and select Properties. A dialog box appears.
6. Click Change Icon under the Shortcut tab then Click Ok in warning box that says shutdown.exe contains no icons.
7. Select an Icon from the list of available images Click Ok twice (once to close the Change Icon window and once to close Properties window). Your shortcut will now have an icon.
8. Right click the shortcut and select Pin to Start. The shutdown icon will now appear on your Start screen.
9. Drag the shutdown icon to a prominent place on your Start screen. We recommend putting it in the first column to the left so you will always see it.
10. Right click the icon and select Pin to Taskbar if you want the shortcut to live on your desktop’s taskbar as well.
11. Repeat the previous steps to create a Restart button. Use the command `shutdown /r /t 0` in the location field.

Comment: Does this need admin privileges? Good one though.

Comment: @JulianKnight - I do not think so but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little addition to existing answers.
The quickest way to shut down Windows 8 for me takes these steps:

1. Press Win key + D -> show desktop
2. Click on empty place on desktop
3. Press Alt + F4
4. Press Enter (to confirm shut down option in drop down list)

I hope it will help someone just as it is helping me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the various other options already mentioned, it is still possible to use the <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to bring up the run box, which will allow you to run the `shutdown` command and its various parameters directly.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. <kbd>Down</kbd>
4. <kbd>Right</kbd>
5. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. 3x <kbd>Down</kbd>
7. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

;)

You could create an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script assigned to a global shortcut to do this for you!

Comment: Great! And windows can be used without a mouse ;)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
2. "Power"
3. "Shut Down"

Answer (score 0):

**HotShut** is a free tiny app which lets shutdown as well as restart, lock, hibernate or log off from your Windows computer instantly from the "system tray" (notification area of the task bar)

[image]

Simply right click and select your desired option.

More info & to download the zip file:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/quickly-shutdown-restart-lock-logoff-windows-computer-hotshut