# power off computer with windows 8 icon

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reboot/shutdown Windows 8 without the mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/408015/how-to-reboot-shutdown-windows-8-without-the-mouse)

I have just updated to Windows 8, but I have a very basic question: How to turn off the computer in Windows 8? Why did Microsoft hide the turn off icon?

Is there a way to put it in a convenient place, for example on the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on desktop and select the `Shortcut` under `New` and now paste the following in the location address

> C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-shutdown-event-tracker_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_ff7f2391995ebcaf\shutdown.exe

Now click `Next` and then `Finish`, now a `shutdown.exe is on your desktop you can change the icon by right click on it and through properties.

Also hit the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and tyoe the following

> shutdown /s

it will shutdown your system within a minute

> shutdown /s /t 0

it will shutdown your system without delay

> shutdown /s /f /t 0

now it will shutdown your system forcefully without delay.

**Why did they remove it from there**

No one can say exactly why but they have changed the interface and given it a new stylish look and to adjust they might have moved it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m6-ExUSFGQ), you can also create a shortcut to "shutdown /s /t 0" (without quotes).
Locking the screen(Windows key + L) will show a shutdown button in the bottom right corner, from there you can select "Shutdown".