# How to add a shutdown tile to the start screen?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

How do I add a tile on the Windows 8 Modern UI that allows me to click that tile to start shutting down the computer?

Comment: There are a couple of answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/408015/how-to-reboot-shutdown-windows-8-without-the-mouse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adapted from [Ben Oostdam's blog](http://www.oostdam.info/index.php/sectie-blog/54-windows8/343-windows-8-create-a-shutdown-button).

1. Go to `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
2. Right click > New > Shortcut
3. Enter `%windir%\system32\Shutdown.exe -s -t 0` as the location
   [image: New Shortcut]
4. Give it a name and click **Finish**
   [image: Finish]
5. Position the icon where you want it:
   [image: Shutdown Metro]

Optional:

1. Right click on the shortcut and select Properties
2. Click the **Change Icon...** button. (There is a power button icon in `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`
   [image: Shutdown icon]

To add the shortcut to the **All Apps** group:

1. In the shortcut properties, go to the **Security** tab
2. Add `All Application Packages` and make sure the **Read** and **Read & execute** permissions are enabled

Comment: @SeiSeiei Just a note "shutdown -s -t 0" will do a full shutdown, so next boot will be slower than if you used the "settings" shutdown, it does a "shutdown -h -t 0" for a hybrid shutdown, which allows for a faster startup.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then select Shutdown.

Comment: That pops up a sidebar, but there is no Shutdown option... unless you click Settings, then do additional clicks...