# Is there a method for 1 or 2 click Shutdown in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I shutdown Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/491008/how-do-i-shutdown-windows-8)

The only method I could find out while usage is drag to top right, then go to settings, click on power button and click again on shutdown. Sounds too much.

Comment: [These](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/shutdown-restart-windows-8) are the only ways. If you feel [adding a shutdown tile](http://superuser.com/questions/494861/how-to-add-a-shutdown-tile-windows-8-modern-ui) is a hack, then the answer would probably be that no, there's no in-built method to do what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press the on/off switch.

Credit [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows8ProductivityWhoMovedMyCheeseOhThereItIs.aspx)

Comment: +1, possibly the quickest/shortest method no matter whether you are at the desktop or the Start Screen, and no "hacks" required (unless you count setting the power button to shut down as one).

Comment: Thanks for the great link .. I felt like a fool. Then I felt I have been played all these years. Now I feel worse.

Comment: @Kang Beer solves the issue of feeling like a fool. Damn, I have been pulling the power cord for years!

Comment: +1 but I hope the option to make the power button actually mean hibernate is still there.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a tile in the start menu for a Windows 8 shutdown.

Step 1: Right-click on a open area of your desktop, then go to New and select Shortcut.
(Credit: Screenshot by Ed Rhee/CNET)
[image]
Step 2: In the location box, type shutdown /p to shut down Windows 8 immediately or shutdown /r /t 0 to reboot Windows 8 immediately. Click Next to continue.
(Credit: Screenshot by Ed Rhee/CNET)
[image]
Step 3: Type a name for your shortcut, then click the Finish button.
Step 4: Right-click on the shortcut from your desktop and select Pin to Start.
(Credit: Screenshot by Ed Rhee/CNET)
[image]
Step 5: Go back to the Start screen and verify that your new shutdown tile appears.

Credit: [Cnet](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57392988-285/how-to-create-a-shutdown-and-reboot-tile-in-windows-8/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and though this might be a solution, i'd rather call it a hack. Win8 has some poor UX.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to go to desktop followed by <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: This also seems to work under Windows 7.

Comment: @Charles I believe it also works in Vista and XP, not that anyone should still be on them...

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a keyboard then `WinKey + i` brings up the settings and you can tap the bower button from there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but too much work here too. 2 keys and then 2 clicks. Again a bad UX example I'd say.